# Azure Function KafkaTrigger (.NET) consuming messages with Avro array schema as root

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, azure-functions, avro, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I have an Azure Function KafkaTrigger (using azure functions kafka extension: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-kafka-extension) which is set to consume messages from Kafka with Avro schema that looks like this:

```json
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "myrecord",
        "fields": [
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

The schema is retrieved from a SchemaRegistryUrl (that I do not control) set on the KafkaTrigger. The events type I try to deserialize into is `KafkaEventData<GenericRecord>[]`:

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public void Run(
    [KafkaTrigger(brokerList: "...",
                  topic: "...",
                  SchemaRegistryUrl = "...",
                  SslCertificateLocation = "...",
                  SslKeyLocation = "...",
                  Protocol = BrokerProtocol.Ssl,
                  ConsumerGroup = "...")] KafkaEventData<GenericRecord>[] kafkaEvents) 
{ ... }
```

When I run the trigger I get the following error:
`Confluent.Kafka: Local: Value deserialization error. System.Private.CoreLib: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'Avro.Generic.GenericRecord'.`

Is there some way to use the KafkaTrigger in Azure Functions to deserialize messages with an Avro schema that has "type": "array" as the root?

Comment: Have you tried putting the square brackets inside of the angle brackets? You're currently trying to define an array of KafkaEventData, not an array of Avro record. Notice the error says it cannot cast an array object into a single GenericRecord

Comment: I have tried using `KafkaEventData<GenericRecord[]>[] kafkaEvents` which results in `Exception binding parameter 'kafkaEvents'. System.Private.CoreLib: Object cannot be stored in an array of this type.`
I have also tried using `KafkaEventData<GenericRecord[]> kafkaEvents` which results in `Exception binding parameter 'kafkaEvents'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: The supplied value was not of type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka.KafkaEventData`1[Avro.Generic.GenericRecord[]]'`

Comment: According to the producer of the events they batch events in Kafka in 1 message when they occur close together (hence the array type as root) so logically `KafkaEventData<GenericRecord[]>[] kafkaEvents` would make sense as I can still receive multiple messages from Kafka in 1 trigger execution, each message containing multiple entries (the array in the schema). But I assume the KafkaTrigger does not know to find the "record" type in the referenced schema and used that as the `GenericRecord`

Comment: Ok I was using the wrong schemas for those tests. The actual error message for both tests above is: `Confluent.Kafka: Value deserializer was not specified and there is no default deserializer defined for type GenericRecord[].`

Comment: `Value deserializer was not specified` seems like a fixable error. In any case, I've not used Azure triggers before, but it's possible it won't give you an array of records (`KafkaEventData<GenericRecord>[]`) , but it will give you one byte array payload (`KafkaEventData<Bytes>`)  You could therefore instead try to manually deserialize the data

Comment: Also, one GenericRecord instance can have an array schema. You therefore shouldn't need to explicitly type it as an array of objects, especially since Kafka deserializers don't typically return any array/collection types, but if it did, you still may need to manually define that with your own implementation